# Generate DKIM Key on Mountain Lion OS X

Tags: email, osx-mountain-lion, email-client, email-signature, dkim

I have been looking around for a way to generate dkim keys on my mac, I have looked into opendkim, there is no brew formula or taps available, tried to compile it from scratch and it required the dkim-milter library which does not compile out of the box on mountain lion, and there was nothing on google for that compile error.

I also tried install amavisd, however, everything I keep coming up with is for mountain lion server...

I am looking for a way to generate dkim keys from my mac, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, simple enough, use genrsa and openssl

```
genrsa -des3 -out dkim.private 1024
openssl rsa -in dkim.private -pubout -out dkim.public
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenDKIM tools are now available in homebrew with name [libopendkim](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/libopendkim.rb) so alternatively you can do

```
$ brew install libopendkim
$ opendkim-genkey -v -s selector -d example.org
opendkim-genkey -v -s selector -d example.org
opendkim-genkey: generating private key
opendkim-genkey: private key written to selector.private
opendkim-genkey: extracting public key
opendkim-genkey: DNS TXT record written to selector.txt
```

Comment: Hello from 2020: `Error: libopendkim has been disabled because it is not maintained upstream!` is the message displayed from `brew install libopendkim` now, unfortunately.